# Duration of counting to a high number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter

I am trying to set the duration of my counter to be slow without having a large duration number set in the code for example:

```
duration: 99999;
```

Originally I had the counter set to a low number but the count is to reach 1,000,000,00 but i want to be able to control how fast this counts.

Here is how I currently have it set up.

```
<div class="counter" data-count="1000000">0</div>
```

and my JS is as follows:

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
  countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

$({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
countNum: countTo
},

{

duration: 99999,
easing:'linear',
step: function() {
  $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
}
});  
});
```

I am a Junior at this so any other recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set how quickly the count is being made, you can try setting the duration (which is measured in milliseconds) to match the `countTo` value. For example, if you want an increment to be made every second, do: `duration: parseInt(countTo)*1000`.

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  }, {
    duration: parseInt(countTo) * 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Ensure that the final value is updated correctly
      // ... especially when using very short durations
      $this.text(this.countNum);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="1000000">0</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @dcmagpies Just remember that even though the duration can be set to a very small value, the end result might not be accurate—you will need to use `complete: function(){...}` to manually set the final value then.